# Learner Question: Why is there a need to use a separate props file when coding Typescript/React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm relearning(!) TypeScript and to a lesser extent React after initially learning things the easy way.

I'm getting confused by the need for a separate props and state file or in particular how they are used with parent and child components and how that is harnessed by either parent or child. I think my main problem is understanding TypeScript and how props and state is used with it.

I'm creating an app that looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Dibf.module.scss';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Page1 } from './Page1/Page1';
import { Page2 } from './Page2/Page2';
import { Header } from './Header/Header';
import { Footer } from './Footer/Footer';
import { Product } from './Product/Product';

import { IDibfProps } from './IDibfProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

export default class Dibf extends React.Component<IDibfProps, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      CurrentUserTitle: null,
      CurrentUser: null,
      CurrentUserGroups: null,
      CurrentUserID: null,
      CurrentUserEmail: null,
      FullName: null,
      UniId: null,
      FilteredItems: [],
      Author: null,
      CurrentUserRole: null,
      Items: [],
      DepartmentsList: [],
      SelectedDept: undefined,
      Id: null,
      JobRef: null,
      Title: null,
      JobTitle: null,
      DateOfBreach: null,
      DateOfDiscovery: null,
      IncidentDetails: null,
      PersonalData: null,
      FormStatus: null,     
      PhoneNo: null,
      Department: null,
      SubDepartment: null,
      LoggedInUser: null,
      LoggedInUserPPDefaultItems: [],
    };
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IDibfProps> {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <h2>App</h2>

          <Header HOW WOULD I GET THIS CHILD FUNCTION TO UPDATE THE STATE OF ITS THIS PARENT?/>

          {/* The different screens will be re-rendered here */}

          <Route path="/screen1" component={Page1} />
          <Route path="/screen2" component={Page2} />
          <Route path="/products/:id" component={Product} />

          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

So you can see the different child components. , ,  etc...

I will have fabric UI fields and controls on each of these child components.
What is easiest to do?:

1. Have the state for ALL controls in the Parent, like I have above and then use the props and state interface file to somehow pass whatever is changed in the controls up to the state (Lifting state up using a handler function?)
2. Or have a state set for each child component and pass props between siblings? How would the separate props/state interface file work in that instance?

I understand how to pass props/state using React but I don't understand how TypeScript does it using the interfaces. I'm guessing it's something to do with the class and render declaration  but not sure.

I need some help from this here community as I'm in a bit of tiz at the moment with this. Imagine learning something for a few months then finding out you know NOTHING!

Can someone provide me a simple explanation with code examples instead of providing links.

Thank you

UPDATE: I've updated the code - please look at the Header function with a request. Please provide a code example(s).

T

Comment: I never use a different file for my props and state interfaces. But of course you can if you feel like that makes your code easier to read

Comment: That's handy to know but I need to know: how do I use these interfaces with the components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is important to point out is that Typescript is duck-typed. These two interfaces are equivalent

```
interface PorpsOne{     
  caption:string     
} 

interface PropsTwo{     
  caption:string     
}
```

Given these interfaces the following construct is OK.

```
function userOne(item:PropsOne){return item.caption;} 
function userTwo(item:PropsTwo){return item.caption;} 


const item = {caption:"Item caption", other:42, properties:null}; 
userOne(item); 
userTwo(item);
```

Having said that, you may define properties you expect to use with a child-component multiple times, once per component file. You also may extract common part, define it once, and import it in the parent and in each child component file.

Typescript does nothing to pass states between parent child, run-time javascript does. Typescript helps you to ensure that required information will be passed by typing and checking those types

INHO it is good direction to try extract shared state and put it into parent and use (1) handler functions to update it.

Therefore

> HOW WOULD I GET THIS CHILD FUNCTION TO UPDATE THE STATE OF ITS THIS
>   PARENT?

```
interface HeaderCanChangeCurrentUser{
  onCurrentUserTitle(title: string): void;
}
//...can be a field of parent class instead of const in render
const onCurrentUserTitle:HeaderCanChangeCurrentUser["onCurrentUserTitle"] = (value:string)=>{this.setState({CurrentUserTitle:value});};
<Header onCurrentUserTitle={onCurrentUserTitle}/>
```

Typescript helps you to formulate which part of the state the component depends on.

BUT again. It is not mandatory to put the interface declaration in a separate file. The declaration can be exported from the component file as well. Yet separate things kinda helps readability, or does it not? It is personal and team preferences after all.

I also can interpret the question in another way. Will typescript help me to declare props for child component to update parent state. That is if I have an interface full of fields will it create "derived/dependent" interface full of onXxx methods to change the parent state. Yes, it does.

But again can't connect this interpretation with the "separate files" part.

Comment: I'm getting the error No overload matches this call on the <Header onCurrentUserTitle={onCurrentUserTitle /> that you provided.

It goes on to say Overload 1  of 2 '(props: Readonly{}>): Header' gave the following error. Type '{ onCurrentUserTitle: (title: string) => void; }'  is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes....' etc.